# moment.js format for unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a unix timestamp to local time using moment.tz .  I've noticed I have to use a format when passing in a date, like this

```
moment.tz(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a', zone).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
```

My problem is when I want to convert from a unix timestamp to calendar like date the conversion fails.  What should I pass for the format string?

I've tried these two formats with no luck

```
var date = moment.tz(publishInterval.DateUnix, 'X', zone).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');


var date = moment.tz(publishInterval.DateUnix, zone).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
```

Comment: What *precisely* is in the variable named `date` in your first example, or `publishInterval.DateUnix` in your second and third examples?  Please give an example.  (Same for `zone`).

Answer (score 5):

have you tried

`moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a')`

as is?

Comment: This will work if the `date` variable is a number, and is in terms of milliseconds.  (Not sure if that's what the OP has or not yet.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a very simple fix for this when using moment.
Simply use the .unix function with moment. Below is an example -

```
var date = moment.unix(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm about 5 years late, but in case anyone stumbled upon this thread and was trying to figure out the answer, here it is...

I had to break down dates into unix time-stamps, so that I could properly .sort() them.

Here is how I converted them back:

```js
let categories = ['2021-08-24', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-22', '2021-08-21', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-20']

//Convert to unix time-stamp looping through array of dates
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    let tempDate = moment(categories[i]).format();
    categories[i] = moment(tempDate).unix();
}

categories.sort();

//Revert Back to 2021-08-24 looping through same array
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    let tempDate = moment.unix(categories[i]).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:SSS a');
    categories[i] = moment(tempDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding some event listener or HTML code that runs your JS on run would be in order to show your code running.